# How to append elements in a list within a list?

Tags: python

I'd like to append elements to a sub-list within a main-list. The number of elements to be appended corresponds to the sub-list position in the main-list.

My code:

```
# define the maximum level of the game
max_level = 3
# create list with length = level
lsx = []
# append empty lists in lsy for every element in lsx
empty = []
lsy = []

def create_list(max_level):
    for i in range(max_level):
        integer = random.randint(1,5)
        lsx.append(integer)
    for j in lsx:
        lsy.append(empty)
    return(lsy)

create_list(max_level)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Desired output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Are you looking for a sequential list in your output? If so, why are you using `random`? Also, you're appending `empty`, so of course you're getting empty lists.

Comment: Well, you're appending empty lists to `lsy`...

Comment: Why did you use `lsy.append(empty)` and not `lsy.append(j)`?

Comment: You never return or use `lsx` after putting those integers in it. You never use `j` at all. Stop using globals and think carefully about what your code does in the simplest possible case.

Comment: Something like `return [list(range(1, n)) for n in range(2, max_level+2)]` would work fine btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need (and shouldn't) use globals. When appending `empty` to `lsy` multiple times you are appending the same object - changing one will change other as well.

You can create the nested lists inside the loop:

```
import random


def create_list(max_level):
    # top level list
    res = []
    for i in range(max_level):
        # nested list
        next_l = []
        for j in range(i+1):
            next_l.append(random.randint(1, 5))
        res.append(next_l)
    return res

print(create_list(3))
```

Output:

```
[[5], [4, 3], [2, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this could work

```
def create_list(max_level):
    res = []
    for i in range(max_level):
        i += 1
        res.append(list(range(i+1))[1:])
    return res
```

Output

```
>>> create_list(5)
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```